# How do I create custom alert message for new alerts - Customizing Alert Notifications and Alert Templates in Windows SharePoint

Tags: alert

I want to change the first message when you create a new alert. See example below:

**Tried this for making a custom alert**

> on added posts:
> [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdeveloperdocs/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0)

**And this works fine, but you cannot change the first alert message here. Any Ideas about where to change this?**

> Alert 'PostsNinja' has successfully
> been added on 'ImageBlog'.  You will
> receive alerts according to the
> delivery method, timing and criteria
> that were selected when the alert was
> created. You can change this alert or
> any of your other alerts on the My
> Alerts on this Site page.

I know how to do this for item added by using the alerttemplate xml file, but can not find for the first message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to avoid sending a confirmation automatically when creating the alert:

```
var newAlert = currentUser.Alerts.Add();
...
bool sendmail= false;
newAlert.Update(sendmail);
```

Then send the subscription manually instead using:

```
SPUtility.SendEmail(myWeb,headers,"You got mail");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx

The email template can for example be stored in a resource file.